# How to access /posts WordPress JSON REST API and filter by post_type?

Tags: json, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have a number of posts in the table wp_3_posts with the post_type "people". This post_type is created using the Admin Columns plugin.

How do I retrieve these?

The documentation for Posts offers filtering by categories or tags but post_type is neither of these.

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/

Thank you :]

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question the right way, you want to get posts of a custom post type with REST API.

You have to set `show_in_rest` and `public` in the arguments when you create the custom post type in wordpress.

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_cpt' );
function my_cpt() {
    $args = array(
      'public'       => true,
      'show_in_rest' => true,
      'label'        => 'My Custom Post'
    );
    register_post_type( 'mycustompost', $args );
}
```

More about this: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-rest-api-support-for-custom-content-types/

With that having set, you can get the posts of post type with using the right parameters in the url.

So if you just want to get posts, you can use:

```
https://yoursite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/mycustompost?per_page=10
```

I would suggest setting the `per_page` to have control if you are getting a lot of posts.

You can also have access to more data without additional HTTP requests using `_embed`

```
https://yoursite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/mycustompost?per_page=10&_embed=wp:term,wp:featuredmedia
```

For example, with this you get taxonomy terms and urls of different featured image sizes.

---

So you do not need to get all posts (and post types) of your website and then filter by post type, but just get posts of this post type instead. You can than do more filtering using global parameters:

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/global-parameters/

With VueJS (in my opinion better performance) this would look something like:

```
fetch("https://yoursite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/mycustompost?per_page=10")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((data => {
            this.mycustompost = data;
        }))
```

Or if using standard javascript something like:

```
let state = {
      posts: [],
      baseUrl: 'https://yoursite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/mycustompost',
      perPage: '?per_page=10',
      wpFetchHeaders: {
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'x-wp-total'
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! This post type is created using the Admin Columns plugin. I have updated my question to reflect that There is no call to register_post_type() for this type in my system. How would I get a list of all of these types using REST?

Comment: Admin Columns is not a plugin for creating custom post types. As I read in the description (https://wordpress.org/plugins/codepress-admin-columns/) there is no functionality to add a new post type. Have you changed the standard post type of wordpress to show different name in menu? I think you have to have added the custom post type some other way, the plugin can not be used for this, as far as I can read it in the plugin description...-